# Grab text from multiple parts of a string which differs in size and convert them into variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to grab specific parts of a string to convert them into variables. I was able to use `str_replace()` to get the output I wanted but since it changes in length especially file paths it just wont cut it.

STRING TEMPLATE:

```
$issue->fields->description = "MSI: YES XPF: NO PKG TYPE: XYZ VENDOR: WXYZ USER CODE: AB APP NAME: ATBTOOL VERSION: 1.0 MEDIA ZIP FILE: \\123.456.78.9\Path\TO\MY\MSI\MSIHelpV1.0.zip INSTALL DIR: G:\MSI EXISTING: NO";
```

This template always stays the same and when this array is dumped there is always a space around the values. The values im trying to grab are:

YES
NO
XYZ
WXYZ
AB
ATBTOOL
1.0 
\123.456.78.9\Path\TO\MY\MSI\MSIHelpV1.0.zip
G:\MSI
NO

So i'm wondering if there is any to maybe specify to grab everything inbetween MSI: & XPF:, PKG TYPE: & VENDOR:, and so forth just a thought any help would be appreciated!

This is the code I've been working with.

```
$stringPosPKG = strpos($issue->fields->description, 'TYPE');
                $stringPosVENDOR = strpos($issue->fields->description, 'VENDOR');
                $stringPosCODE = strpos($issue->fields->description, 'CODE');
                $stringPosAPP = strpos($issue->fields->description, 'APP');
                $stringPosVERSION = strpos($issue->fields->description, 'VERSION');
                echo "</br>";
                echo "PKG Begins At " . $stringPosPKG;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "VENDOR Begins At " . $stringPosVENDOR;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "CODE Begins At " . $stringPosCODE;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "APP NAME Begins At " . $stringPosAPP;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "VERSION Begins At " . $stringPosVERSION;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "</br>";
                $pkgType = substr( $issue->fields->description, 33, -217 );
                $vendorName = substr( $issue->fields->description, 48, -203 );
                $userCODE = substr( $issue->fields->description, 67, -184 );
                $appName = substr( $issue->fields->description, 83, -163 );
                $versionNum = substr( $issue->fields->description, 103, -147 );
                echo "</br>";
                echo "PKG Title: " . $pkgType;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "VENDOR Title: " . $vendorName;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "CODE CODE: " . $userCODE;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "APP NAME: " . $appName;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "VERSION: " . $versionNum;
                echo "</br>";
                $versionNumStrRArray = ["."];
                $versionNumStrR = str_replace($versionNumStrRArray, "_", $versionNum);
                echo "MSI NAME: MSI_" . $pkgType . "_" . $vendorName . "_" . $userCODE . "_" . $appName . "_" . "$versionNumStrR";
```

OUTPUT:

```
PKG Begins At 27
VENDOR Begins At 40
CODE Begins At 61
APP NAME Begins At 73
VERSION Begins At 94


PKG Title: ABC
VENDOR Title: WXYZ
CODE CODE: AB
APP NAME: ATBTOOL
VERSION: 1.0
MSI NAME: MSI_ABC_WXYZ_AB_ATBTOOL_1_0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you should be using regular expressions for this one. Something like that:

```
<?php

function parseFoo(string $foo): array
{
    $splitInput = [];

    preg_match_all(
        '/(?<key>[^\s][A-Z\s]+): (?<value>[\pL\pP\d]+)/',
        $foo,
        $splitInput
    );

    return array_combine(
        $splitInput['key'] ?? [],
        $splitInput['value'] ?? []
    );
};

$input = "MSI: YES XPF: NO PKG TYPE: XYZ VENDOR: WXYZ USER CODE: AB APP NAME: ATBTOOL VERSION: 1.0 MEDIA ZIP FILE: \\123.456.78.9\Path\TO\MY\MSI\MSIHelpV1.0.zip INSTALL DIR: G:\MSI EXISTING: NO";

echo json_encode(
    parseFoo($input)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was able to just output it using -> ```echo parseFoo($input)['MSI'];``` and so forth!

Comment: I just have one question question about this ```["p INSTALL DIR"]=> string(6)``` its dumping the p from into the next key?

Comment: For some reason ```MEDIA ZIP FILE: \\123.456.78.9\Path\TO\MY\MSI\MSIHelpV1.0.zip``` is being stripped out of the array and the p from zip ends up there -> ```["p INSTALL DIR"]```

Comment: I fixed most of it now I didnt account for spaces in the path!